# Use PNG as custom map iOS

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I need to use a PNG as custom map of an indoor place. I don't need navigation but some places should be clickable like what we have in built in map. In android this is possible with `MapView` but I didn't find anything for iOS to do that. Can someone help me out how to start and do this?

Comment: what functionality do you need ? is it possible just to use the png pic as a background of the screen and place buttons on top of it ?

Comment: I need scroll and zoom in my map @TungFam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A while back Apple added the ability to provide custom map overlay tiles. It isn't as simple as providing a PNG. You will need to create a database of map tiles at different scales, following a specific naming convention, and then provide a tiled map overlay.

I suggest looking at this blog post:

[**Custom and Offline Maps Using Overlay Tiles from VIGGIOSOFT**](http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2014/01/21/custom-and-offline-maps-using-overlay-tiles/)

It goes into quite a bit of detail on what's required.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. but it's so hard to implement

Comment: Yes, it will be a lot of work. However, you should feel lucky. I had a client that needed offline mapping in iOS 6, before MapKit tiled overlays were available, so I built a custom tiled rendering and mapping system completely from scratch. Talk about a **lot** of work!

Comment: @DuncanC the link seems broken. I need the same repeating tile over and over everywhere on the map if the user is offline. Just so the map doesn't look broken. Would you have any tips on how to implement that? I still need to place pins on such map